# Subscriber callback inside class not recognized C++

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a class that contains a ROS subscriber and the callback function. I have done this following the ROS [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks) and according to other answers that I have found (for example [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/108551/using-subscribercallback-function-inside-of-a-class-c/)).

I have included a snippet of my code below:

```
class VelocityCommandSubscriber{
public:
    geometry_msgs::Twist velocity_msg;
    std::string velocity_type;
    VelocityCommandSubscriber(geometry_msgs::Twist velocity_msg, std::string velocity_type)
    {
        velocity_msg = velocity_msg;
        velocity_type = velocity_type;
        velocitySubscriber = nH.subscribe<std_msgs::Float64>("/command_velocity_"+velocity_type,10, &VelocityCommandSubscriber::VelocityCallback, this);
    }
    void VelocityCallback(std_msgs::Float64::ConstPtr& velocity_cmd_msg)
    {
        //Callback code here
    }
protected:
    ros::NodeHandle nH;
    ros::Subscriber velocitySubscriber;
};
```

However, whenever I run this code I get the following error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe<std_msgs::Float64>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, void (VelocityCommandSubscriber::*)(std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&), VelocityCommandSubscriber*)’
   81 |             velocitySubscriber = nH.subscribe<std_msgs::Float64>("/command_velocity_"+velocity_type,10, &VelocityCommandSubscriber::VelocityCallback, this); |
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? I am using ROS noetic and am relatively new to ROS and c++ so I may very well be reading over something simple.

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414261/subscriber-callback-inside-class-not-recognized-c++/) by [DuffRumkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/145231/duffrumkins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-04-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2023-04-12**:
Your callback argument looks different from the example from the ROS Answers, can you try it with normal `const` instead of `ConstrPtr`? Or use the suggested `boost::bind`?

**Comment by [DuffRumkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/145231/duffrumkins/) on 2023-04-12**:
I tried it with `const` and I get the exact same error. I also tried boost::bind, but that just gave me another similar error. Is this maybe new in noetic since the other answers would have been for an older ROS version?

**Comment by [DuffRumkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/145231/duffrumkins/) on 2023-04-16**:
@ljaniec , I think you may have been correct. As I said in a reply to the answer I think defining the type in the subscriber template was causing mismatch errors. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This roscpp subscriber callback compiles just fine in noetic:

```
void VelocityCallback(const std_msgs::Float64::ConstPtr& velocity_cmd_msg) { }
```

In c++, this code is not going to do what you want it to do:

```
velocity_msg = velocity_msg;
velocity_type = velocity_type;
```

If the same compile error continues to happen after you fix the code, you should also try doing a clean build (if using catkin_make, delete the top-level `build` and `devel` directories in your catkin_ws.)

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DuffRumkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/145231/duffrumkins/) on 2023-04-16**:
This naming issue was indeed a problem that I completely looked over. Thanks!

I managed to get my code to build by changing this, but I also had to remove the `<std_msgs::Float64>` from where I defined `velocitySubscriber` as a subscriber. I think the fact that I was defining the type as `Float64` there while using `Float64::ConstPtr` in the callback function was causing a mismatch error.

Thanks again for your help!